# Bing map integration into iPhone application

Tags: iphone, bing

Is it possible to integrate Bing maps into a native iPhone application?

Comment: I am interested in this as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bing map now has a native SDK for iOS. Check this: http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2011/05/05/new-bing-maps-ios-sdk.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use Bing Map geodata instead of google map:

Use Bing's REST or SOAP webservice:
If I understand it correct you can even build your own map out of the Imagery Service:

To get started you need to get the appID and then in case you use SOAP get the wsdl:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980844.aspx

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial should help you when you have questions with the generation from a wsdl: http://brismith66.blogspot.com/2010/05/iphone-development-accesing-soap.html